# Initialize interface in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: firebase, interface, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my FirebaseMessagingService, I want to use interface because whenever I get notification, I want to do some operation in my activity. So is it possible to use Interface in FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: There is no way to trigger an operation on an Activity when something happens at a Service. That's because Services are designed to work in the background. Your activity might not be visible when the service triggers the operation and that would generate an error. May I ask: What kind of operation are you trying to do in your activity when a new notification arrives?

Comment: Also: Should this operation happen only when the activity is visible? And not happen when the activity is invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably thats the only way. Create a Broadcast receiver and feel free to comunicate with your notifications

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931325/8383365