# FirebaseMessagingService's onBind method is final. how make it bound service?

Tags: android, firebase, android-livedata

I want to bind my custom firebase service to the MainActivity class. if it was a normal service, it would be easily done by making the service implement the **onBind** method, but it is not available because this method is set final in the superclass of FirebaseMessagingService class. I want to bind the service in order to use the LiveData variable set inside this class in the MainActivity class.

I have searched for best practices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917403/using-kotlin-coroutines-to-replace-localbroadcastmanager-for-firebase-messaging) and read this [documentation about bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) but no luck. I tend to use LiveData somehow but I feel it is not working until I somehow manage to bind the service. am I missing something?

Comment: You can not bind to the extends of `FirebaseMessagingService`. easy way to use Singleton LiveData or another observer/subscriber pattern like `RxJava` or `Flow`

Comment: @CôngHải Don't I need to bind service even if I use a singleton approach? btw, thanks for your comment.

Comment: sure, you don't need bind to service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by @CôngHải, I can use a singleton object with LiveData inside it to communicate between service and activity without the need of binding the service to activity.