# Can a Broadcast Receiver send information to an Activity only if it is active without starting a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that gets triggered on geofencing events and either "clocks in" or "clocks out" with the server. If my application's "Attendance" activity is already open I would like it to display the clocking status change but I don't want the Broadcast Receiver to start the activity if it's not open - in other words display the change "live" while the activity is open only.

The way I imagine doing this is with the Broadcast Receiver sending an Intent to the activity but name "startActivity()" doesn't sound encouraging unless there are any special flags I can pass to prevent starting an Activity that isn't already open - I can't seem to find any.

The other option would be to constantly poll the value while the activity is open but it doesn't seem optimal so I would only use it if there wasn't another way and I can't think of a reason why it couldn't be possible with Intents.

Comment: Use an interface similar to `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Could you possibly explain a bit more, maybe with a simple code sample? Just to be clear I have an Activity and I have a Broadcast Receiver which outlives several lifecycles of the Activity. The Broadcast Receiver is only created once and then gets instantiated by Android on every geofencing event. I want the Receiver to tell the Activity, if it's awake of any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to accomplish the same task. One is registering a listener like the following example:

**MainActivity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
        Receiver.setOnReceiveListener(new Receiver.OnReceiveListener() {
            public void onReceive(Context Context, Intent intent)
            {
                //Do something.
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Receiver.setOnReceiveListener(null);
    }
}
```

**Receiver**

```java
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static OnReceiveListener static_listener;

    public static abstract interface OnReceiveListener
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
    }

    public static void setOnReceiveListener(OnReceiveListener listener)
    {
        static_listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(static_listener != null) {
            static_listener.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have your `BroadcastReceiver` send a broadcast `Intent`. Your `Activity` should register a listener from this broadcast `Intent` and if it gets triggered, it can update the UI.

---

Here's an example:

Declare a private member variable in your `Activity`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

In `Activity.onCreate()`, register the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("my.package.name.CLOCK_STATUS_CHANGE");

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Here you can update the UI ...
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

And in `onDestroy()` you can unregister it (probably not necessary, but cleaner):

```
if (receiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   receiver = null;
}
```

In your `BroadcastReceiver` that detects the geofencing event, you should create and send a broadcast `Intent`:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("my.package.name.CLOCK_STATUS_CHANGE");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: That wakes up the Activity if it's not active though which is not what I want. Ideas on how to send an Intent only to active Activities?

Comment: What do you mean "wakes up the `Activity`? If the `Activity is in the background (paused), it will stay paused, it will not resume and it will not be brought to the foreground.

Comment: According to my understanding, when the Activity is not even running in the background, or when the app is removed from the "Recent Apps" list or killed (not paused), then a broadcast message to the Activity will start the activity up.

Comment: No, that is only the case if the `BroadcastReceiver` is declared in the manifest. In that case, a broadcast `Intent` will start the `BroadcastReceiver` (not any `Activity`). In your case, you have a dynamic (not manifest-declared) `BroadcastReceiver`, which is only alive as long as your `Activity` is alive. This `BroadcastReceiver` listens even if the `Activity` is paused, but does not "start the `Activity` up" if it is triggered. It simply runs the code in the `onReceive()` method. If your app is dead, the `BroadcastReceiver` isn't even listening.

Comment: I added a code example.

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is. My `BroadcastReceiver` is in fact declared in the manifest and geofencing events do start my Broadcast Receiver even when the rest of the app is dead. I need it like that because GF events need to be clocked with the server.

Comment: But I also see what you are suggesting now. Which is to have a second Broadcast Receiver (this time created dynamically by the Activity and should only have the lifetime of the Activity) and have the first Broadcast Receiver send intents to the second one on GF events. Nice. I like the decoupled architecture. I can confirm that @Darkman's answer also works after testing.